# Validation error "Column must be a valid timestamp"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

So I am creating forms on oracle but I am unable to enter time into the TIMESTAMP field.. i am only able to enter date, if I even try to add time with date, It throws an error. Here is what it looks like:
[image]

so basically, It only allows me to enter date, but not the time..

and my datatype for deptime and arrivaltime is TIMESTAMP(6), In fact, when i enter values using sql statement, it does it perfectly fine with time.

Comment: can we see your code, please?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts You mean the datatype and all I gave to each field?

Comment: Not familiar with forms at all, but... when you created the form, somewhere you must have told "the form" what format model to accept for timestamps. Either that, or there is a default (which obviously you need to override). If "creating the form" means "writing some code yourself", look for a TO_TIMESTAMP(...) call which takes the user input as argument, and where the format model is 'DD-MON-RR'. While you are there, CHANGE the format model to 'DD-MON-YYYY' (while you also add the time component of the model); there is absolutely no excuse for two-digit year in 2017.

Comment: @mathguy I didn't.. And it accepted the same format as my table. which is timestamp(6)

Comment: This is APEX, not Oracle Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have intrinsic "formats" for columns of type `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` - your table doesn't specify any format. The input/output format model is supplied by the application, in this case, Oracle Application Express (APEX).

On the item you can specify the **Format Mask**, e.g. `DD-Mon-RRRR HH24:MI:SS`